# Getting Error : SEVERE: Unknown KieSession name: in drool 6.0.0

Tags: java, ant, drools, drools-fusion

I compiled the drool project using ant. I tried to run it with

```
java -cp .:../../lib/* com.myproject.sample.MomAlertApp
```

I am getting an error:

```
SEVERE: Unknown KieSession name: MomAppKs
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.myproject.sample.MomAlertApp.testMe(MomAlertApp.java:28)
at com.myproject.sample.MomAlertApp.main(MomAlertApp.java:38)
```

As I already set the pom.properties as:

```
groupId=com.myproject
artifactId=drool
version=0.1
```

Project Directory:

test_project:

```
 ----src
      ---com.myproject.sample
                    ---trigger
                          ---drool
                                ---facts
                                   --Person.java
                          ---rules
                                   --rule.drl
     ---META-INF
           ---kmodule.xml
           ---maven
                ---pom.properties

----test
       ---src
            ---com.myproject.test
                    ---myProjectTest.java


---lib
```

I do not want to use maven as whole product demand ant build for now.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you have defined a seccion called: MomAppKs inside the kmodule.xml file? can you share that info?

Comment: yes I defined that "MomAppks"